# two notification with two different id's but 2nd replace to the 1st one

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

i want to set 2 different or more `notification` with different `id` 's but the second one replacing the first. i have a reciver class extending `broadcastReciever`:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION    = "notification";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    Log.i("ShowNotifyID:", "" + id);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }

}
```

And in my activity i create `notifications` with unique `id` and pass them to reciver.Each  `noteID` is unique and i retrive it from `DataBase`.when the user click on button to set notification the method `onClickSet()` will be called.

```
public class ReminderActivity extends Activity {

int               noteID;
String            noteText;
DatePicker        datePicker;
TimePicker        timePicker;
NoteManagerHelper db;
int               isReminder;
NoteItem          item;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_activity);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

    Intent reminderIntent = getIntent();
    noteText = reminderIntent.getStringExtra("noteText");
    noteID = reminderIntent.getIntExtra("noteID", 0);
    db = new NoteManagerHelper(this);
    isReminder = db.getIsReminder(noteID);
    if (isReminder == 1) {
        setShowingTimeInDatePicker();
    }

}


private void setShowingTimeInDatePicker() {
    NoteItem item = db.getAnItem(noteID);
    datePicker.updateDate(item.reminderYear, item.reminderMonth, item.reminderday);
    Log.i("DATEPICKER:" + item.reminderYear, "" + item.reminderMonth + "-" + item.reminderday);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(item.reminderHour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(item.reminderMinute);
}


public void onClickSet(View v) {//onClick of the set button
    //if isreminder is not 0 that means this note already have a notifaction in receiver, we need to cancel it first and start a new one
    if (isReminder == 1) {
        removeReminderFromService();
    }
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long delay = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    item = new NoteItem(noteID, noteText);
    item.isReminder = 1;
    item.reminderYear = datePicker.getYear();
    item.reminderMonth = datePicker.getMonth();
    item.reminderday = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    item.reminderHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    item.reminderMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

    db.setReminder(item);

    scheduleNotification(getMyNotification(noteText), delay);

    finish();

}


public void onClickRemoveReminder(View v) {
    if (isReminder == 1) {
        removeReminderFromService();
        db.setIsReminderToDB(noteID, 0);
        isReminder = 0;
        Toast.makeText(ReminderActivity.this, "Reminder removed successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(ReminderActivity.this, "No reminder set yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


public void removeReminderFromService() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) (ReminderActivity.this).getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(noteID);
    Log.i("RemoveNotifyID:", "" + noteID);

}


public void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, noteID);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + futureInMillis, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);

}


private Notification getMyNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Rnote");
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return builder.getNotification();
    }

}
```

i did read similar questions. but the solution mostly was about using different `id's`.Can anyone help me?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the ***notifiaction_id*** in pending intent also,

Pass the notification_id

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notification_id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Instead of 0 in pending intent

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```